# Turning a Block of PHP into a Variable

Tags: php

I have some PHP that I have to add to my page a couple times and instead of just pasting it a bunch of times I would like to turn it all into a php variable. I have searching but don't think I know the correct term to search for to achieve this.

Here is what I'm trying to turn into 1 variable:

```
session_start();
$time = time();
$hash = md5($key . $time);
$str = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$url = str_replace("0239", "738", $str);
header("Location: http://google.com");
exit;
```

Comment: Place it in a new file and then use `require('filename.php')` where you want it injected into your other files.

Comment: You should [define a `function`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) and call it where needed, although this code looks like something that may be at home in an `include()`'ed PHP header file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Watch out using that as a function or a require because of the `session_start()` problems.

Comment: You don't appear to ever need/use anything but `header()` so why repeat it?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Or anything except `header()`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver that was an example of some of the code I have, but i do need them :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't turn it into variable, but into a function.

```
function functionName($key) {
  session_start();
  $time = time();
  $hash = md5($key . $time);
  $str = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  $url = str_replace("0239", "738", $str);
  header("Location: http://google.com");
  exit;
}
```

Now you can anywhere in code call

```
funcitonName($key);
```

to execute your code.